# React app only at production. Error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: reactjs, webpack

So, I'm having the following error on production

`localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

I`m confused, because this is happening only in production, and on every page, like it was requesting a HTML thinking that it is a JS file

[image: the error on production]

I had this problem once in production, when I access some route like /company/55, I got this same error, I solved that with the publicPath on webpack compile, but this error is new to me, and it is happening on all pages, the app isn`t working at all in production.

my webpack.config

```
const APP_ENTRY_PATH = paths.base(config.dir_client) + '/main.js'

webpackConfig.entry = {
  app: __DEV__
    ? [APP_ENTRY_PATH, `webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=${config.compiler_public_path}__webpack_hmr`]
    : [APP_ENTRY_PATH],
  vendor: config.compiler_vendor
}

// ------------------------------------
// Bundle Output
// ------------------------------------
webpackConfig.output = {
  filename: `[name].[${config.compiler_hash_type}].js`,
  path: paths.base(config.dir_dist),
  publicPath: config.compiler_public_path
}

// ------------------------------------
// Plugins
// ------------------------------------
webpackConfig.plugins = [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin(config.globals),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: paths.client('index.html'),
    hash: false,
    favicon: paths.client('static/favicon.ico'),
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body',
    minify: {
      collapseWhitespace: true
    }
  })
]

if (__DEV__) {
  debug('Enable plugins for live development (HMR, NoErrors).')
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  )
} else if (__PROD__) {
  debug('Enable plugins for production (OccurenceOrder, Dedupe & UglifyJS).')
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        unused: true,
        dead_code: true,
        warnings: false
      }
    })
  )
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

Debugging with Pause on Caught Exceptions I found this

```
function(e, t) {
    var n = function() {
        try {
            Object({
                toString: 0
            } + "")
        } catch (e) {
            return function() {
                return !1
            }
        }
        return function(e) {
            return "function" != typeof e.toString && "string" == typeof (e + "")
        }
    }();
    e.exports = n
```

the error is that one:

> Paused on exception: "Type Error: Cannot convert object to primitive value."

**Edit 2:**

Debugging with Caught Exceptions i have the following breaks

- Break 1:

At jquery-2.1.1.min.js:formatted

> Paused on exception: 'DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '*,:x' is not a valid slector.'.

```
ib(function(a) {
                var b = e.createElement("input");
                b.setAttribute("type", "hidden"),
                a.appendChild(b).setAttribute("name", "D"),
                a.querySelectorAll("[name=d]").length && q.push("name" + M + "*[*^$|!~]?="),
                a.querySelectorAll(":enabled").length || q.push(":enabled", ":disabled"),
                a.querySelectorAll("*,:x"),
                q.push(",.*:")
            })),
            (c.matchesSelector = $.test(s = o.matches || o.webkitMatchesSelector || o.mozMatchesSelector || o.oMatchesSelector || o.msMatchesSelector)) && ib(function(a) {
                c.disconnectedMatch = s.call(a, "div"),
                s.call(a, "[s!='']:x"),
                r.push("!=", Q)
            }),
```

Then it go to another break on the some code, for another selector

> Paused on exception: 'DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '[s!='']:x' is not a valid slector.'.

- Break 2:

Then another break at vendor.js:formatted

> Paused on exception: 'TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null'.

Code:

```
function a() {
            var t;
            try {
                t = window.localStorage[p]
            } catch (e) {}
            if (typeof t === s)
                try {
                    var n = window.document.cookie
                      , r = n.indexOf(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=");
                    r && (t = /^([^;]+)/.exec(n.slice(r))[1])
                } catch (e) {}
            return void 0 === l.levels[t] && (t = void 0),
            t
        }
```

After that it breaks on some

```
throws new Error
```

line codes, in the same vendor.js:formatted

first on:

```
var B = !1;
    try {
        throw new Error
    } catch (q) {
        B = !!q.stack
    }
```

then on:

```
function u() {
        if (B)
            try {
                throw new Error
            } catch (t) {
                var e = t.stack.split("\n")
                  , n = e[0].indexOf("@") > 0 ? e[1] : e[2]
                  , r = a(n);
                if (!r)
                    return;
                return W = r[0],
                r[1]
            }
    }
```

- Break 3

After all that it goes to app.js:formatted and breaks at the

> Paused on exception: "Type Error: Cannot convert object to primitive value."

```
function(e, t) {
    var n = function() {
        try {
            Object({
                toString: 0
            } + "")
        } catch (e) {
            return function() {
                return !1
            }
        }
        return function(e) {
            return "function" != typeof e.toString && "string" == typeof (e + "")
        }
    }();
    e.exports = n
```

I'm still lost

Comment: Are you able to pinpoint the method call that is returning the error?

Comment: Nope man, I'm completely lost on this, there isn't no message error saying what error is that or from where it comes

Comment: But it seems to me that it is requesting the Html file like it was a JS file, to it throws a syntax error

Comment: Go to the Sources tab in debugger and enable ["Pause on Exceptions"](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/automatically-pause-on-any-exception) to see if that shows you anything else.

Comment: @BradBumbalough updated the question with what I found out

Comment: Awesome.. stepping in the right direction. Do you recognize any of the calls leading up to the one that failed? There should be a call stack provided. Oftentimes the one that fails is a library/utility function that gets invoked as a result of your own code.

Comment: This usually happens to me when I have a route wrong in either Express, or my react-router. The front end requests some JS or JSON, but gets back my home page or a friendly 404 page instead.

Comment: @JeffMcCloud this is happening in all my pages, the production env uses just the bundled pack, don't see any problem in my routes js

Comment: @BradBumbalough can't recognize any of this calls on the call stack ... but some errors occurs before the one that I provided in the question.
They are errors with jquery, and they are DOMExceptions 
`Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '*,:x' is not a valid selector`, the falling code:
`a.querySelectorAll("*,:x")`

Comment: Check the network tab in Chrome Dev Tools. Look for requests that should receive JSON (calls to a .json file, REST calls etc), and look at the response to each.  One of them will have HTML as the response and not JSON. If you look at the HTML, you can usually figure out what went wrong (e.g. bad URL, error thrown on server, etc)

Comment: @JeffMcCloud going to see it, did some updates on the question, with the breaks that I have when debugging

Comment: @BradBumbalough check my updates on my question

Comment: So those errors make it seem that it could be something like JeffMcCloud mentioned about returning a HTML page instead of json. Those could just be side effect errors thrown by the browser libraries.

Comment: @JeffMcCloud THANKS, find it out, shit, I hate when is that simple, I was executing the bundle command without the API_URL env var, so the bundled pack was calling a nonexistent. The API request was returning a Html file, of my home page.

Thanks so much Jeff